# What could be these polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

Trying to build an approximation, I encountered the following polynomials
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & x-3 \\
 3 & x^2-30 x+45 \\
 4 & x^3-273 x^2+1575 x-1575 \\
 5 & x^4-2460 x^3+43470 x^2-132300 x+99225 \\
 6 & x^5-22143 x^4+1123650 x^3-8004150 x^2+16372125 x-9823275 \\
 7 & x^6-199290 x^5+28423395 x^4-431531100 x^3+1830403575 x^2-2809456650 x+1404728325
\end{array}
\right)$$

What I noticed is that

- the constant term is $(-1)^{n}\,\frac{2^{2 n+1} \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma
     \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\pi }$
- the coefficient of the second highest power is $\frac{3}{8} \left(1-9^n\right)$
- the coefficient of the third highest power is $\frac{15}{128} \left(2-3^{2 n+5}+5^{2 n+4}\right)$ but this does not help me much.

Any idea or suggestion would be very welcomed

Comment: Hi Claude. I computed the roots of the first polynomials : they are all real and positive and the biggest root represents a huge percentage of the trace: $97.8 \%, 99.3 \%, 99.7 \%$ for degrees 3,4,5 resp. A (non rare) phenomena which could hopefully be compensated by considering reciprocal polynomials ( P(1/x) instead of P(x))...

Comment: FWIW the constant term is [A079484](https://oeis.org/A079484), which has several references listed, though not obviously related to these polynomials.

Comment: small thing, next diagonal, namely 1575,  132300, 8004159, I get: if you add $\frac{175}{1024}$  to each term,  recurrence has characteristic polynomial $(x-9)(x-25)(x-49)$

Answer (score 1):

$\{-1575, -132300, -8004150, -431531100,...\}$:

$\dfrac{35}{1024}\bigg(5 - 3^{2 n + 8} + 5^{2 n + 7} - 7^{2 n + 6}\bigg)$

$\{1, -30, 1575, -132300, 16372125, -2809456650,...\}$:

$-(-1)^{n + 1} 2^{2 n} (n + 1) Pochhammer\bigg(\dfrac{3}{2}, n\bigg) Pochhammer\bigg(\dfrac{5}{2}, n\bigg)$

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks & cheers :-)